# C++ Disambiguation: subobject and subclass object

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

Basically what the title says. I have been referring to Base objects as subobjects. Is that correct and would it also be correct that `subobject` == `superclass object`? Which one is preferred?

The `subclass` means the derived class and the `subclass object` means the derived class' object, right?

The confusion for me is that `subclass object` != `subobject`.

If any of this is right, anyway..

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard "subobject" nor "subclass", but it makes me think of either nested classes or member variables.  In no case would I think you meant the "superclass".  "sub"!="super".  Where did you find these terms?

Comment: [intro.object]/2 "Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject, a base
class subobject, or an array element."

Comment: @Mooing Look at this page on [Virtual Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) It says: *"This feature is most useful for multiple inheritance, as it makes the virtual base a common subobject for the deriving class and all classes that are derived from it."*

Comment: @DyP: well, that shows me wrong, as well as all the answers I see so far.  Post as answer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The C++ Standard has a clear definition of what a *subobject* is. That said, many people don't (precisely) use the language of the Standard when talking about C++. One popular example is the term *object*. From languages like Java, some people tend to use *object* only in the sense of *instance of a class*, which wouldn't apply to `int`. In the terms of the C++ Standard, an `int` is an object.

What the Standard says in [intro.object]/2:

> Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects*. A subobject can be a *member subobject*, a *base class subobject*, or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a *complete object*.

This is to be understand in the context of the (possible) memory layout. It isn't fully specified, but most likely looks like this:

```
class Foo { int i; };
class Bar : public Foo { int j; };
```

An object of type `Bar` could look like this in memory:

```
+-Bar-------------------+
|  +-Foo-----+          |
|  |  int i  |  int j;  |
|  +---------+          |
+-----------------------+
```

That is, the members of `Foo` are members of `Bar` like the direct members of `Bar`. Every object of `Bar` therefore "contains" an object of type `Foo`. Also consider

```
Bar b;
Bar* pBar = &b;
Foo* pFoo = &b;
```

```
+-Bar-------------------+
|  +-Foo-----+          |
|  |  int i  |  int j;  |
|  +---------+          |
+--^--------------------+
^  |pFoo
|pBar
```

To allow `pFoo` to point to complete objects of type `Foo` and to subobjects of type `Foo`, there needs to be a whole and (memory-wise) independent object of type `Foo` inside any object of type `Bar`. It might not be known at compile-time which one is the case, but the code produced for `pFoo->i = 5;` has to work for both.

This all is specified under the as-if rule, i.e. it doesn't have to be that way, but it has to observably behave that way. Also, it isn't required that this is the actual memory layout, but it is a common implementation.

---

In [intro.object]/4

> If a complete object, a data member, or an array element is of class type, its type is considered the *most derived class*, to distinguish it from the class type of any base class subobject; an object of a most derived class type or of a non-class type is called a *most derived object*.

There's no use of the word *super* in the Standard other than *supersede* and *superset*. There's *base class* and *derived class* (as well as ~ object).

---

Outside the C++ language Standard, the term *superclass* is used to refer to a *base class*, and the term *subclass* is used to refer to a *derived class*. This refers to the OO concepts and classification, much like a *Species* is a sub-category of a *Genus* in biology.

But in this categorization, there's no memory layout, hence no need to talk about *subobjects*. There are *instances* or *objects* (in the OO sense) *of classes*, so you could talk about *objects of a superclass* and *objects of a subclass*. The confusion might stem from abbreviating this *object of a subclass* to *subobject*, and mixing language of OO with language from the C++ Standard.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be thorough and correct and I have marked it as such. Just curious, how would you personally refer to `Foo` in `Bar` if it came up in conversation?

Comment: @user2672807 I'd call them [metasyntactic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) ;) The rest depends on the context. As C++ supports multiple and private inheritance, I prefer using *base class* and *derived class* when the topic is specifically C++ and not OO in general.

Comment: Ah. Well I'm referring to an instance of a class, i.e. an object. Do you think calling the base part of a derived object as `base object` is acceptable or correct? Or could I say "that's set in the base part of the object" or something like that?

Comment: @user2672807 As the quote from [intro.object]/2 says, subobjects are also objects, so it isn't wrong to call the *`Bar` base class subobject within/of `b`* the *base class object of `b`* (`Bar` has only one base class). But to me, the latter sounds a bit weird and might lead to confusions; the prefix *sub* emphasizes that the referred object isn't the complete object. *base class part of the object* should be fine, too. For general OO, there's the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but this doesn't require that there's a distinct *subobject* of a *superclass*.

Comment: I'm still a little confused please bear with me. `Foo` is a base class subobject of `Bar`, is it not? Because what you wrote above seems to imply Bar is a base class subobject of `b` (which is just `Bar b` according to your post)? Sorry if I misunderstand and thanks for your patience.

Comment: @user2672807 I've tried to avoid the class names `Base` and `Derived` and confused myself ;) You're correct, it should have been *`Foo` base class subobject within/of `b`*.

Answer (score 6):

This happes when general object oriented terms are mixed with C++ related terms.

- subobject: Any object that is stored within another object (array elements, base class objects and data member objects).
- sub-class: A general object orientation term refering to what in C++ is called the "derived class"
- super-class: A general object orientation term refering to what in C++ is called the "base class".
- complete object: Any object that is not stored within another object.

Just a little hint - When talking in C++ land, I try to use the C++ terminology. When talking in Java land, I'm trying to talk with the Java terminology.

Answer (score 3):

*Subobject* is C++ terminology for an object that's part of another object; either a member or a base class.

*Subclass* is terminology used in other languages, and more general discussion of inheritance, to mean a derived class. This comes from the convention of drawing class hierarchies as upside-down trees, with the root at the top. C++ doesn't use this term, perhaps because of the potential confusion you describe.

To avoid confusion when discussing inheritance in C++, use the standard terminology of *base* and *derived* classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think most often sub-object confusingly refers to the base-class-related parts of the sub-class object (e.g. some vtable pointers), especially in a setting when multiple inheritance is involved. I'd suggest avoiding the term and stick to the more stablished terminology (Super/Sub, Base/Derived).

Answer (score -1):

I would call it parent object maybe?