# How do subobjects work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, clang, subobject

What is the meaning of standalone square brackets inside of a C array of a custom type?

```c
typedef enum {
    BAR_1 = 0,
    BAR_2,
    BAR_3,
} bar_types;

typedef struct {
    int is_interesting;
    int age;
} foo_s;

static foo_s bars[] = {
    [BAR_1] = {1, 2},  /* What is being done here? */
    [BAR_2] = {1, 41},
    [BAR_3] = {0, 33},
};
```

In the above code, what is the meaning of `[BAR_1] = {1, 2}`?  When is it possible to use standalone square brackets?

I've noticed that if I add duplicate value in brackets, clang gives an warning about subobject initialisation.

```c
static foo_s bars[] = {
    [BAR_1] = {1, 2},
    [BAR_2] = {1, 41},
    [BAR_3] = {0, 33},
    [BAR_3] = {0, 33},
};

-----

$clang example.c
example.c:17:19: warning: subobject initialization 
  overrides initialization of other fields within its
  enclosing subobject [-Winitializer-overrides]
    [BAR_3] = {0, 33},
              ^~~~~~~
```

What is a C subobject?

Comment: Those just designate specific array elements to be initialised.  The enum values act like the corresponding `int` values, so `[BAR_1] = {1, 2}` becomes `[0] = {1, 2}`, meaning the first struct in the array (index 0) gets initialised with `is_interesting` as 1 and `age` as 2.

Comment: For what a subobject is, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451683/c-disambiguation-subobject-and-subclass-object

Comment: "subobject" is any object contained within another object.

Comment: The notation is one species of 'designated initializer'.

Comment: @racraman That is a C++ question. This is about C.

Answer (score 2):

this is struct initialization, the "subobject" is the instance of the struct that is getting initialized.

Your warning comes from trying to initialize the same array position twice.

also see [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards)

Comment: Warning, not error. It is valid to initialize it twice.

Comment: Of course, warnings shouldn't be ignored: -Wno-initializer-overrides. :-)