# Difference in Address of base and derived objects using *this vs using & operator

Tags: c++, radix, derived, this-pointer

Can someone try to explain me why i get a difference in address of base and derived object while using this pointer and & operator. Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
     A()
     {
         cout<<"Base Address "<<this<<endl;
     }
};
class B:public A
{
    public:
    B()
    {
        cout<<"Deri Address "<<this<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b;

}

The O/P is 
Base Address 0x7fff500e9bdf
Deri Address 0x7fff500e9bdf
```

Both are same.

When i add two more statements in the main as shown below

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

```
class A
{
    public:
     A()
     {
         cout<<"Base Address "<<this<<endl;
     }
};
class B:public A
{
    public:
    B()
    {
        cout<<"Deri Address "<<this<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    A a;
   cout<<&a<<endl<<&b<<endl;

}
```

The O/P is as shown below

```
Base Address 0x7fff82c696df
Deri Address 0x7fff82c696df
Base Address 0x7fff82c696de
0x7fff82c696de
0x7fff82c696df
```

Now I could clearly see the address differs

a) What could be the reason for this difference
b) One more thing i wanted to know is if the base sub object in derived class is exactly same as the base object? I am confused about this because if we say in a base class if we have a variable x and if we have a derived class for this base class(non polymorphic case) now if we talk about the base sub object in derived, is it the same x present in base class is also present in the base sub object of derived class (i mean the variable with same address in both base and base sub object in derived) or we have a separate copy of x in both base and base sub object of derived(i mean the variable with different address)

```
Please clarify?
```

Comment: `this` points to instance of object not to "type". Since you have two instances of objects `a` and `b` there are two different `this` values one for each object. I wonder why it is strange for you?

Comment: What does "base sub object" mean?

Comment: Base sub object means the base part of the derived object. what i don't understand is this* contains the objects address and why does it differ from the address when we print the object's address using & operator?

Comment: no it does not differ because of the &, it differs because they are different objects.

Comment: @MarekR, If you observe the first output where we print both Base and Derived addresses inside constructors using this *, we have the same address values for both base and derived .We don't have two different this values for each object. we have same value for both objects. so i am confused at this point.

Comment: logs which You've included says something else (last digit is different for for each object).

Comment: FYI interesting things will happen when you will use multiple inheritance. This example should be clear and obvious.

Comment: @MarekR, sorry but I could still see the same value for both in the first case in the logs i added. This is the O/P i added in the first case.                             
 Base Address 0x7fff500e9bdf
Deri Address 0x7fff500e9bdf

Answer (score 1):

You  have **two** objects: **a** and **b**:

a with address  0x7fff82c696de

b with address  0x7fff82c696df

Answer (score 1):

Why do you get what you see? well it's because `a != b`
You do create 2 objects:

```
A a;
B b;
```

It clearifies if you add another parameter to your class A's constructor

```
class A
{
    public:
     A(std::string name)
     {
         cout<<name<<"'s Base Address "<<this<<endl;
     }
};
```

and modify your `main` function a bit

```
int main()
{
    B b("b");
    A a("a");
   cout<<"a: "<<&a<<endl<<"b: "<<&b<<endl;

}
```

Now your output will look like this

```
b's Base Address 0x7fff82c696df
b's Deri Address 0x7fff82c696df
a's Base Address 0x7fff82c696de
a: 0x7fff82c696de
b: 0x7fff82c696df
```

Now you can see that thr result of `& operator`and `*this` are equal. You just have tow different objects with, of course, two different addresses.
You also see that for derived class `B`, `this` has the same value in `B`s and `A`s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to clarify for you is understanding difference between **class** vs **object**. A **class** is a blueprint whereas **object** is an instance of the class.

So, if you don't create an instance of the class, then you have nothing on the memory.

In the first case, the addresses printed are the same because you created one instance. It make sense to have the same address because of having only one single object.

In the second case, the addresses are different because of having two different objects (two instances of the class are created) not because of using `&`. So, the following code prints the same addresses.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Address with this pointer: " << this << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << "Address with & operator: " << &a << std::endl;
}
```

**Edit: Why represents the same address for sub-object**

As I mentioned in the comments, I never heard the term *sub-object*. But I got the below definition from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18452270/4735781).

**subobject:** Any object that is stored within another object (array elements, base class objects and data member objects).

An object naturally occupies a memory and any sub-object of the object needs to seat somewhere in that memory. 
The *first created sub-object* (in terms of order of definition) gets the first portion of the memory, *second created sub-object* gets the second portion of the memory right after first object and so on.
So, *first created sub-object* has the **same starting address** with the object itself. In the following code, the fist created object is instance of **Class A** ( So A and C have the same address) just because **Class A** is inherited before than **Class B**. If you change `class C : public A,  public B` to `class C : public B,  public A`, then objects of class B and class C would be the same.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Address of Sub-Object A: " << this << std::endl; }
    int x;
};


class B
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "Address of Sub-Object B: " << this << std::endl; }
    int y;
};

class C : public A,  public B {
public:
    C() : A() , B() { std::cout << "Address of Object C:     " << this << std::endl; }
    int z;

};

int main()
{
  C c;
}
```

**PS:** if you think about composition rather than inheritance, then it might be more easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Regarding your comment                               
     "In the first case, the addresses printed are the same because you created one instance. It make sense to have the same address because of having only one single object"    yes here we have only one instance which is derived instance but that also contains base sub object as well right. I mean to construct a derived object we have two things to do . One is construct a base subobject and then the remainig derived object . Both these objects put together makes a complete derived object.

Comment: No, that is not right. When you create a derived class's object, you did not create the base class's object. You just created one object of the derived class. By the way, there is not such a terminology "base sub object".

Comment: ok. May be I got this info from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451683/c-disambiguation-subobject-and-subclass-object

Comment: Alright, I got what you mean now and edited my answer. Please take a look.